# AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperation block is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using AFNetworking to send a multipart form to a web-server, and i'm having some trouble with my `AFHTTPRequestOperation`. It's success and failure blocks are never called, after i start it.

Here is my code (a resume of it)

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[ServerAPI sharedClient] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:postUrl parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:picture.picture_data name:@"InputFile" fileName:picture.name mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
    }];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[ServerAPI sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest: request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        NSLog(@"%f", (totalBytesRead / (float) totalBytesExpectedToRead));
    }];         
    [[ServerAPI sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

I can see the logs of the progress, but success and failure blocks are never called.

`picture.picture_data` is a `NSData` initialized with a `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.7)`
ServerAPI is a subclass of `AFHTTPClient`, and `sharedCliend` is a singleton method.

Which are the reasons for AFNetworking don't call my blocks, not even with an proper error message?

Thank you all!

**Edit**

I do a get request with the same URL just before this one, and it works as usual. The URL i'm using is: `part/_layouts/UploadEx.aspx?List=%7BD432BF97-7175-40C1-8E0D-27D8661CBC90%7D&RootFolder=%2Fpwa%2Fpart%2FLibrary&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Emysite%2Ecom%2Fpwa%2Fpart%2FLibrary%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&IsDlg=1`

Comment: ever find out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, check your `postUrl` . The `BaseURL+postURL` must be valid. Try upload image using normal web browser using URL `BaseURL+postURL`.

**Edit**

method `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` does not work for file uploading, but works for json/html fetching.
Try use

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFJSONRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
        NSLog(@"%f", (totalBytesRead / (float) totalBytesExpectedToRead));
    }];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure");
    }];

[[ServerAPI sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: I make a get request with the same URL just before it, it works just as usual... I'm going to post the URL i'm using in the question, Thank you!

Comment: Is your server has limitation for uploaded file size?

Comment: No success =(
I tried to create the operation without my API Class, and start the operation with the `start` method, but nothing works...